# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method get_Item(Int32)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I hope someone can help me. I have a relative simple program that query data from an Entity and bind the query to `dataGridView1` but I got the below error which I have tried to resolve over 30 mins without progress.

> System.NotSupportedException: 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell get_Item(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'

```
using (var context = new myContext())
{
    var query = context.mySoftWare
        .Where(s => s.Software.Contains(dataGridView2.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString()))
        .Select(r => new {r.SID, r.Software,r.Vendor,r.Version });

    dataGridView1.DataSource = query.ToList();
}
```

Comment: You can't mix database database level code and "application" code in an entity query.  it doesn't know how to translate the application code in to something the database understands.

Comment: You should pull `dataGridView2.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString()` out, before the query, in to a simple variable, and use the variable in the query.

Comment: This has been asked millions of times. All you needed was to search for "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code you write inside your `Where` is *translated* to SQL. The engine doing that doesn't know how to translate `dataGridView2.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString()` into SQL.

Simple way to fix this is to make that value its own variable

```
var value = dataGridView2.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

var query = context.mySoftWare
    .Where(s => s.Software.Contains(value))
    .Select(r => new { r.SID, r.Software, r.Vendor, r.Version });

dataGridView1.DataSource = query.ToList();
```

<sub>Now let's just hope the sql engine knows how to translate "Contains".</sub>

Comment: It works! I wish the error just could tell me that I was stupid to mix codes instead of a very hard to understand error - Thanks!!!!

Comment: Odds are that `Contains` will be fine, since it is off of a property on `s`, which comes from an `Expression` on `Software`, which is (at least it looks like) a DbSet<>.  Meaning it is a navigation property, so it should be `IEnumerable<>`.

Comment: @UlinkSecret "[...]this method cannot be translated into a store expression." seems like a *fairly* helpful error to me, if you think about it.

Comment: actually, I did my search but I could not get it. When I saw the answers, they were referring to creating a new list `Int` as the issue was due to `SID` being `Int` not `String` . I should have looked more close the error-indicator but I was frustrated